# fscanf reads a line that does not exists in a file

Tags: c, scanf

I'm on a Fedora 15 computer and I have a simple code that looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x[50], y[50];
    int i;
    FILE *f_in = fopen("readtest.dat","r");

    if (f_in == NULL) printf("No file...\n");
    else
    {
        i = 0;
        while (!feof(f_in))
        {
            fscanf(f_in,"%d %d",&x[i],&y[i]);
            printf("%d %d\n", x[i], y[i]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("I've read %d data.\n", i);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The file to be read is this

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

But I don't know why the output looks like this.

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
1250259108 1250140145
I've read 6 data.
```

I was thinking that I left a blank new line in the file, but I didn't. I double checked the file with both gedit and vim and no blank lines were found. Why am I reading this unexisting line?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a new line escape character in your `fscanf`

```
fscanf(f_in,"%d %d\n",&x[i],&y[i]);
```

Also dont forget to `fclose` your file

**EDIT**

I tried it and here are the results.

Without the `\n`

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
-1216418984 1
I've read 6 data.
```

With the `\n`

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
I've read 5 data.
```

Comment: That was the problem, adding the escape character worked. But I can't figure out why though.

Comment: `fscanf` processes all whitespace characters the same, so you could just do `"%d %d "`. If you really want to verify that it's done correctly, line-by-line, you should use `fgets`, which is infinitely harder to get wrong.

Comment: Nice point about the white space. I agree with `fgets` but i just wanted to provide a working answer as close to the original code as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Probably last call to `fscanf` functions failed.

> These functions return the number of input items assigned.  This can
>   be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of a matching
>   failure.

Check its return value before printing. Something like:

```
v = fscanf(f_in,"%d %d",&x[i],&y[i]);
if (v) {
    // printf goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As user786653 said (by reference, at least) in his comment, "while !feof" is the *wrong* way to read a file in C. feof doesn't return true until you've hit the end of the file, and actually tried to read past it. So your program does an extra read, which fails.